# How do I revert broken Build Task in my VSTS account?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have tried to add additional configuration options to an existing VSTS build/release task from the [official repository](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks).

To test it, I used the [tfs-cli](https://github.com/Microsoft/tfs-cli) to upload the task to my VSTS account. However, it appears to be broken since the code was based on some newer Vsts Task SDK version that has not yet been published to my VSTS account.

Since I used the same task guid as the official task, I have updated the official one efficiently and left it broken.

How do I revert these changes and get back to the latest official published version of the VSTS build task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delete the task using `tfx build tasks delete`, the baked in version of the task should restore itself. If it doesn't upload it manually using `tfx`.

You may be able to find the previous version of the task in the `tasks` folder of your build agent if you have a private agent.

Comment: Do you know if official tasks gets restored automatically, or is just a guess? Otherwise I'll have to do some digging in the repo history to find last good version.

Comment: Was my first attempt at customizing a build task, and right after I saw the task fail, I knew I had missed the guid :-(

Comment: Wise lesson... It's much easier when you wrap it in an extension. Easy to turn on and off.

Comment: Thx, will try wrapping in extension next time I fool around with build tasks.

Comment: I deleted the broken task, and the old version came back. Pure magic :-)